# help me with perl win32 gui module

Tags: perl, win32gui

I have code some Perl win gui and I want to make something like a picture that I have attached. I have a problem to make a table. Let me know how can I do that.

[image]

Comment: [`Win32::GUI`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32::GUI), [`Tk`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tk), [`Wx`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Wx) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](http://perl-win32-gui.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/docs.cgi?doc=grid) example.

It uses [MFC grid control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/gridctrl.aspx).